# Filter Views based on Webform Submission Data and Current User Email

Tags: views, webforms

I've got a webform that collects an email address.  What I want to do is build a view based on that email address and the email address of the current user that is logged in.  Basically, show all the webform links that the currently logged in user's email address has been submitted in the different webforms and deny access to any other webform that those don't match.

I've been able to get the email address from the submitted value, but I'm having issues getting the current user's email.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding a relationship with the Webform Submission data and then under the contexual filter using that relationship and providing a default value using php code:

global $user;
$user->mail;

Then I validated it using php code as well to prevent unauthorized access to the view.